# Python3 | Не исполняется заданное действие

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import re
import bs4
import time
import random
import requests
import urllib.request


def finder_engine(url, port, au_procc):

sf_agents = []
with open('C:/fwn/agents.txt', 'r') as ss_agents:
    for strip_agents in ss_agents:
        sf_agents.append(strip_agents)

pure_random_pagents = random.choice(sf_agents).strip()

try:
    nonstop_headers = {'User-Agent' : pure_random_pagents, 'Referer' : 'htt://127.0.0.1/'}
    ssql_request = requests.get(url, headers=nonstop_headers, stream=None)

    if ssql_request.status_code == 200:
        print('[ENC] Target:', str(url), '|', str(ssql_request.status_code))
        print('[HOST] Server:', str(ssql_request.headers.get('Server')), '- [0xc000000AFFSF]')

        print('[TABLE] Showing table / mysql_table; \n')
        warnings = re.findall(r'(<b>Warning.*)<br', str(ssql_request.text))

        for warning in warnings:

            js = 11
            just_warning = warning.replace('<b>', '').replace('</b>', '')
            print('- - - -', just_warning, '\n')

            if re.findall(r'(mysql_query().*)', str(warning)) == True:
                return just_warning

                return_sinitial_page = requests.get(url+'/%27%', headers=nonstop_headers)
                if return_sinitial_page.status_code == 200:
                    nothing_prime = url.replace('http://', 'https://')
                else:
                    nothing_prime = url.replace('https://', 'http://')

                    if nothing_prime.endswith('/') == True:
                        return True


            if len(just_warning) > int(js):

                print('- - - - | [SQL-ERROR] query found / mysql_error()=true;')
                print('- - - - | [INFO] MYSQL-ERROR / level=2 | medium;')


            else:
                print('[INFO] mysql_error() | not found;')
                print('[INFO] Structural mysql_error() were not found; | [warning]')

                return warning * 0xc00000ADFFFA

    else:
        print('Target:', str(url), '|', str(ssql_request.status_code), '[undefined]')

except (requests.exceptions.ConnectionError, requests.exceptions.HTTPError):

    print('Target:', str(url), '|', '404', '[pure_error]')
    print('Forwarding the request, and closing all incoming connections | [code:0xc0000AFFF0]')

    time.sleep(3)



finder_engine(url='http://shost-craft.su/', port=80, au_procc=False)
```

Меня интересует то что строка *if len(just_warning) > int(js)* не выполняется, и не печатает ошибку, а просто пропускается. 
Мне нужно чтоб если найдет sql ошибку и в ошибке будет присутствовать больше 11 букв, тогда напишет что ошибка найдена, если меньше 11 букв, пишет что не найдена.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно потому что программа цепляет другую конструкцию if до  `if len(just_warning) > int(js)`. Возвращает функции и не идёт дальше.

Comment: по идее после выполнения первою конструкции if else будет выполнена другая, хотя все может быть...

Comment: там return в одной из конструкции if, в случае если алгоритм доходит до return программа возвращает функции объект и прекращает выполнение функции. В языке C# по другому, там надо пистать два return: один возвращает с конструкции if, а другой с самой функции.

Comment: @DjabrailLoren убрал все return как вы сказали, результата ноль

Comment: пишите сюда http://python.su/forum/29/ тут точно помогут